Any electric field is necessarily potential?
In electrostatics it is well known that $\nabla \times \vec{E} = 0$, and the domain of definition of $\vec{E}$ can have holes and voids. A potential $V$, s.t. $\vec{E} = - \nabla{V}$ is often used instead of $\vec{E}$. However, the domain of definition of $\vec{E}$ can be quite holey, so it is possible for it not to be simply connected. This means that $\vec{E}$ is in general only locally potential. But in physics the existence of a global potential is always assumed. So I am wondering what are the conditions of promoting the local solutions to a global one?
It is probably worth noting that I am assuming that the field, up to a multiplicative constant, is given by $\vec{E} = \int{\frac{\rho(\vec{d})}{\vec{R}^2(\vec{r}, \vec{d})} \hat{\vec{R}}(\vec{r}, \vec{d}) dV(\vec{d})}$ everywhere where the integral makes sence. I am guessing that under suitable assumptions on $\rho$ (like being smooth everywhere but on a set of measure zero?), it is always possible to find a global solution?

I would say that in a potentially holey domain, you must have
$$\oint \vec{E}(\mathbf{r}) \cdot d \mathbf{r} = 0.$$
The potential difference is then
$$V(b)-V(a) = - \int_a^b  \vec{E}(\mathbf{r}) \cdot d \mathbf{r}.$$
This can be reduced to your curl-free requirement plus the requirement that the line integral around any hole must vanish.

Why must we have that the line integral of $\vec{E}$ vanishes? The condition $\nabla \times \vec{E} = 0$ alone is not enough to guarantee this, as can be seen from the field $\vec{A} = (- \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}, 0)$ and a unit circle loop in the xy-plane

@WhyNót the line integral needs to vanish on a closed loop so that the global potential that the original poster requests is single-valued. If you want a "potential" that is not single-valued then it doesn't need to vanish. Of course, the line integral doesn't need to vanish on a line integral that is not a closed loop.

Of course (A continuous vector field $\vec{E}$ is potential in a domain $D$) <=> (The line integral of $\vec{E}$ around any closed loop in $D$ vanishes). What I don’t understand is where you get this condition from for an arbitrary electric field, for $\nabla \times \vec{E}$ in $D$ is in general not equivalent to the vanishing of the line integral of $\vec{E}$ around every closed loop
